# Struggling with parboxes' width and placement in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, parbox

I am trying to update my own resume/cv in LaTeX. I haven't needed to typeset anything in several years, so my LaTeX is very, very rusty. I took a look at several "cv" classes I like (limecv, fortysecondscv) for inspiration and am now learning TikZ.

My problem is that when I try to place text elements over the design elements, all parboxes turn out too wide by approx. 0,5 cm. In addition, they are not placed exactly where I expect them to be, but ca. 1 mm away. Are there some kind of "whatever-sep(s)" I need to set to 0, or what am I missing?

Below is a MWE showing the boxes and the size I want them to be, with a grid in the background. If you count the squares, you  notice the boxes are all a little too wide.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

% Define margin size
\newlength{\cvMargin}
\setlength{\cvMargin}{1.25cm}

% Set papersize and basic layout
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    noheadfoot,
    nomarginpar,
    margin=\cvMargin,
    showframe
    ]{geometry}

% Define width of main and side columns
\newlength{\cvSideWidth}
\setlength{\cvSideWidth}{0.33333\paperwidth}
\newlength{\cvSideTextWidth}
\setlength{\cvSideTextWidth}{\cvSideWidth-2\cvMargin}
\newlength{\cvMainWidth}
\setlength{\cvMainWidth}{\paperwidth-\cvSideWidth}
\newlength{\cvMainTextWidth}
\setlength{\cvMainTextWidth}{\cvMainWidth-\cvMargin}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% \convertto{mm}{1pt}
\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture, overlay,
  shift={(current page.north west)} % Needed for correct help grid origin
  ] 

  \draw[help lines]
      (0,0) grid ++(\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
   
  \node[left] at (current page.east)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\paperwidth}
          {\centering{}paperwidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\paperwidth}\ cm}
        }
      };

  \node[left,yshift=-5ex] at (current page.east)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\cvSideWidth}
          {\centering{}cvSideWidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\cvSideWidth}\ cm\hfill}
        }
      };   

  \node[left,xshift=-\cvMargin,yshift=-10ex] at (current page.east)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\cvSideTextWidth}
          {\centering{}cvSideTextWidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\cvSideTextWidth}\ cm\hfill}
        }
      };
      
  \node[right,yshift=-15ex] at (current page.west)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\cvMainWidth}
          {\centering{}cvMainWidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\cvMainWidth}\ cm\hfill}
        }
      };
      
  \node[right,xshift=\cvMargin,yshift=-20ex] at (current page.west)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\cvMainTextWidth}
          {\centering{}cvMainTextWidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\cvMainTextWidth}\ cm\hfill}
        }
      };        
      
  \node[right,xshift=\cvMargin,yshift=-45ex] at (current page.west)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\cvMainTextWidth}
          {\lipsum[2-3]}
        }
      };
      
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `node` has a defult `inner sep` which is not zero. This separation is the space between its contents and border.

You don't `draw` the nodes, therefore you don't see their borders but the `fbox` ones. If you want `fbox` adjust to their positions, use a `inner {x|y}sep=0pt` in nodes.

In following code I've added some red nodes to see the effect.

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{calc}

% Define margin size
\newlength{\cvMargin}
\setlength{\cvMargin}{1.25cm}

% Set papersize and basic layout
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    noheadfoot,
    nomarginpar,
    margin=\cvMargin,
    showframe
    ]{geometry}

% Define width of main and side columns
\newlength{\cvSideWidth}
\setlength{\cvSideWidth}{0.33333\paperwidth}
\newlength{\cvSideTextWidth}
\setlength{\cvSideTextWidth}{\cvSideWidth-2\cvMargin}
\newlength{\cvMainWidth}
\setlength{\cvMainWidth}{\paperwidth-\cvSideWidth}
\newlength{\cvMainTextWidth}
\setlength{\cvMainTextWidth}{\cvMainWidth-\cvMargin}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% \convertto{mm}{1pt}
\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture, overlay,
  shift={(current page.north west)} % Needed for correct help grid origin
  ] 

  \draw[help lines]
      (0,0) grid ++(\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
   
  \node[left] at (current page.east)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\paperwidth}
          {\centering{}paperwidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\paperwidth}\ cm}
        }
      };

  \node[left, draw=red, inner sep=0pt] at ([yshift=8mm]current page.east)
      {\parbox{\paperwidth}
          {\centering{}paperwidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\paperwidth}\ cm}
      };

  \node[left,yshift=-5ex] at (current page.east)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\cvSideWidth}
          {\centering{}cvSideWidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\cvSideWidth}\ cm\hfill}
        }
      };   

  \node[left,yshift=-5ex, draw=red, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.east)
      {\parbox{\cvSideWidth}
          {\centering{}cvSideWidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\cvSideWidth}\ cm\hfill}
      };   

  \node[left,xshift=-\cvMargin,yshift=-10ex] at (current page.east)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\cvSideTextWidth}
          {\centering{}cvSideTextWidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\cvSideTextWidth}\ cm\hfill}
        }
      };

  \node[left,xshift=-\cvMargin,yshift=-15ex, draw=red, inner xsep=0pt] at (current page.east)
      {\fbox{\parbox{\cvSideTextWidth}
          {\centering{}cvSideTextWidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\cvSideTextWidth}\ cm\hfill}}
      };
      
  \node[right,yshift=-15ex] at (current page.west)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\cvMainWidth}
          {\centering{}cvMainWidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\cvMainWidth}\ cm\hfill}
        }
      };
      
  \node[right,xshift=\cvMargin,yshift=-20ex] at (current page.west)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\cvMainTextWidth}
          {\centering{}cvMainTextWidth: \convertto{cm}{\the\cvMainTextWidth}\ cm\hfill}
        }
      };        
      
  \node[right,xshift=\cvMargin,yshift=-45ex] at (current page.west)
      {\fbox{%
          \parbox{\cvMainTextWidth}
          {\lipsum[2-3]}
        }
      };
      
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]